# Time consts in Java?

Tags: java, date, time, constants

Is there a Java package with all the annoying time constants like
milliseconds/seconds/minutes in a minute/hour/day/year? I'd hate to duplicate something like that.

Comment: Day/year is anything but constant.

Comment: That's why he's said the 'annoying' time constants :-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) contains classes such as [Days](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html), which contain methods such as [toStandardSeconds()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Hours.html#toStandardSeconds()). So you can write:

```
int seconds = Days.ONE.toStandardSeconds();
```

although it seems a little verbose, and perhaps is only useful for more complex scenarios such as leap years etc.

Comment: See the [`DateTimeConstants`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeConstants.html) class in Joda-Time as well.

Comment: FYI: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: The drawback is that you cannot use them in annotations, as they have to be compile time constants

Answer (score 156):

I would go with java [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) if you are not including joda-time in your project already. You don't need to include an external lib and it is fairly straightforward.

Whenever you need those "annoying constants" you usually need them to mutliply some number for cross-unit conversion. Instead you can use TimeUnit to simply convert the values without explicit multiplication.

This:

```
long millis = hours * MINUTES_IN_HOUR * SECONDS_IN_MINUTE * MILLIS_IN_SECOND;
```

becomes this:

```
long millis = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);
```

If you expose a method that accepts some value in, say, millis and then need to convert it, it is better to follow what java concurrency API does:

```
public void yourFancyMethod(long somePeriod, TimeUnit unit) {
    int iNeedSeconds = unit.toSeconds(somePeriod);
}
```

If you really need the constants very badly you can still get i.e. seconds in an hour by calling:

```
int secondsInHour = TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(1);
```

Comment: Totally agree with your solution to avoid unnecessary dependency on third party library

Answer (score 40):

If on android, I suggest:

[android.text.format.DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#WEEK_IN_MILLIS)

```
DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS
DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS
DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS
DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS
DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS
DateUtils.YEAR_IN_MILLIS
```

Answer (score 40):

### Java 8 / java.time solution

As an alternative to `TimeUnit`, you might for some reason prefer the [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class from **java.time** package:

```
Duration.ofDays(1).getSeconds()     // returns 86400;
Duration.ofMinutes(1).getSeconds(); // 60
Duration.ofHours(1).toMinutes();    // also 60
//etc.
```

Additionally, if you would go deeper and have analyzed how Duration.ofDays(..) method works, you would see the following code:

```
return create(Math.multiplyExact(days, SECONDS_PER_DAY), 0);
```

where `SECONDS_PER_DAY` is a package protected static constant from [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class.

```
/**
 * Seconds per day.
 */
static final int SECONDS_PER_DAY = SECONDS_PER_HOUR * HOURS_PER_DAY;

//there are also many others, like HOURS_PER_DAY, MINUTES_PER_HOUR, etc.
```

I think it is safe to assume that if there would be any package, which would defined "all the annoying time constants like miliseconds/seconds/minutes" as you call them, I believe Java SDK Developers would have use them.

Why are this `LocalTime` constants package protected and not public that is a good question, I believe there is a reason for that. For now it looks like you really have to copy them and maintain on your own.

Comment: any comments on *why* someone might prefer Duration over TimeUnit?

Comment: `Duration.ofDays(1).getSeconds()` will create and throw away an object to do its work, comparing to `TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1)` that only performs calculations.

Comment: I think there is absolutely no reason to use Duration if all you need them to do is convert to a value. It is preferable to use Duration though in your API if that's what you need, in some cases this will be more readable then specifying value and unit as 2 separate arguments.

I will remember to update my answer sometimes soon to indicate that.

Comment: What about readability? I, for one, think `ofDays(1)` is clearer than `toSeconds(1)` in its meaning - I cannot imagine anyone to mistake 1 as the number of seconds when I do `ofDays(1)`, but I can imagine that happening for `toSeconds(1)`.

Answer (score 15):

The Java [TimeUnit](http://www.uni-muenster.de/ZIV.BennoSueselbeck/java/jdk1.5.0_01/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) seems to be what you want

Answer (score 12):

Joda Time also has a [`DateTimeConstants`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeConstants.html) class with things like MILLIS_PER_SECOND, SECONDS_PER_MINUTE, MILLIS_PER_DAY, etc, etc.

Comment: FYI: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I use for getting milliseconds.

```
import javax.management.timer.Timer;

Timer.ONE_HOUR
Timer.ONE_DAY
Timer.ONE_MINUTE
Timer.ONE_SECOND
Timer.ONE_WEEK
```

Comment: Another bonus of this solution is that it works if you need constants rather than method calls, such as when using them in annotations.

Answer (score 5):

While `TimeUnit` discussed in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15255571/642706) and `Duration` discussed in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35128143/642706) probably more directly addresses the Question, there are some other handy units-of-time features in Java.

## java.time

For units, see the [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum:

- [`FOREVER`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#FOREVER)
- `ERAS`
- `MILLENNIA`
- `CENTURIES`
- `DECADES`
- `YEARS`
- `MONTHS`
- `WEEKS`
- `DAYS`
- `HALF_DAYS`
- `HOURS`
- `MINUTES`
- `SECONDS`
- [`MILLIS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#MILLIS)
- `MICROS`
- [`NANOS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#NANOS)

The [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) has sophisticated enums for [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) and [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html). So rather than pass around a mere number or string, you can pass full-fledged objects such as `DayOfWeek.TUESDAY` or `Month.FEBRUARY`.

The java.time framework also includes classes such as `MonthDay`, `YearMonth`, and `Year`. Again, you can pass full-fledged objects rather than mere numbers or strings to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide type-safety.

### Converting between `TimeUnit` and `ChronoUnit`

We can easily convert between `TimeUnit` and `ChronoUnit`. See the new methods added to the older class, `TimeUnit`.

- [`TimeUnit.of( ChronoUnit )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#of(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit))
- [`TimeUnit::toChronoUnit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#toChronoUnit())

## ThreeTen-Extra project

The [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project provides additional classes to work with java.time. These include: `DayOfMonth`, `DayOfYear`, `AmPm`, `Quarter`, `YearQuarter`, `YearWeek`, `Days`, `Weeks`, `Months`, `Years`, and `Interval`.

Answer (score 2):

One more approach with already baked (for multiple call) `Duration` instances (and 0 math operations):

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.getDuration().getSeconds()
```

Answer (score 2):

If the constants are to be used as Compile-time constants (for example, as an attribute in an annotation), then `Apache DateUtils` will come in handy.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;
```

```
DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_SECOND
DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_MINUTE
DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_HOUR
DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_DAY
```

These are primitive long constants.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
              60 * 1000 miliseconds in 1 minute
                     60     seconds in 1 minute
                      1      minute in 1 minute
                   1/60       hours in 1 minute
              1/(60*24)        days in 1 minute
          1/(60*24*365)       years in 1 minute
1/(60*24*(365 * 4 + 1))     4 years in 1 minute
                                                * 60            is in 1 hour
                                                * 60 * 24       is in 1 day
                                                * 60 * 24 * 365 is in 1 year
                                            etc.
```

Create them yourself, I guess, is the easiest. You can use the `Date` and `Calendar` classes to perform calculations with time and dates. Use the `long` data type to work with large numbers, such as miliseconds from 1 Januari 1970 UTC, `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to obtain the values `Calendar` have all fields related to time management, with some simple reflection you can do

Field[] fields = Calendar.class.getFields();

```
for (Field f : fields)
{
  String fName = f.toString();
  System.out.println(fName.substring(fName.lastIndexOf('.')+1).replace("_", " ").toLowerCase());
}
```

this will output:

```
era
year
month
week of year
week of month
date
day of month
day of year
day of week
day of week in month
am pm
hour
hour of day
minute
second
millisecond
zone offset
dst offset
field count
sunday
monday
tuesday
wednesday
thursday
friday
saturday
january
february
march
april
may
june
july
august
september
october
november
december
undecimber
am
pm
all styles
short
long
```

from which you can exclude what you don't need.

If you need just constants you have them: `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`, `Calendar.YEAR` and so on..